# System.IO doesn't have the Exists method

Tags: entity-framework, system.io.file

I'm writing a code where i want to create, open,delete,... .txt files.
I added "using System.IO", but when I write "File.Exists(path)",
where path is the address of the file, the compiler tells me that this method doesn't exist and suggests that i should create it.

I'm using vs2017 with a windows form application and i'm using Entity framework to access a db.

Comment: Do you have another `File` class in your solution? Try using the full syntax `System.IO.FileExists(path)`.

Comment: `System.IO.File.Exists(path)` (missing dot).

Comment: Yes i do have a table in my db named File, maybe it's the error. I will try and use the full syntax, thank you so much!!